# Conversion operator causing compilation error

Tags: c++, casting, stdstring

I have implemented a string-like class, called Str, and want to add a conversion to bool type, in order to use a Str object as a condition.

The Str class is quite simple and relies on another template class called Vec, which is similar to the STL vector class. Below I have copied the main parts of the definition

```
class Str
{

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Str&);

private:
    Vec<char> data;

public:
    typedef Vec<char>::size_type size_type;
    typedef Vec<char>::iterator iterator;
    typedef Vec<char>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return data.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return data.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return data.end(); }

    //[...]

    char& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
    const char& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }
    Str& operator+=(const Str& s)
    {
        std::copy(s.data.begin(), s.data.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
        return *this;
    }

};

Str::operator bool() const
{
    if (data.size() > 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Everything works fine, except that now, if I try for example to do the following:

```
Str greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";
```

then I get a compilation error, saying "'operator +': 2 overloads have similar conversions, could be 'Str operator +(const Str &,const Str &)' or 'built-in C++ operator+(const char [8], int)'.

I understand the reason for the error, but I am not sure how to fix it. How can I get around this?

Thanks.

EDIT: below I have added a minimal, complete and verifiable example:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Str
{

private:
    std::vector<char> data;

public:
    typedef std::vector<char>::size_type size_type;
    typedef std::vector<char>::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::vector<char>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return data.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return data.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return data.end(); }


    // default constructor must be defined explicitly, since non-default constructors are also defined
    Str() { }
    Str(const size_type n, const char c) : data(n, c) {  }
    Str(const char* cp)
    {
        std::copy(cp, cp + std::strlen(cp), std::back_inserter(data));
    }
    // Since this is a template, the iterators can be anything: pointers in an array of chars, std::vector<string> iterators, std::std::vectortor<string> iterators, std::list<string> iterators, etc.
    template <class In> Str(In b, In e)
    {
        std::copy(b, e, std::back_inserter(data));
    }
    char& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
    const char& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }
    Str& operator+=(const Str& s)
    {
        std::copy(s.data.begin(), s.data.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
        return *this;
    }
    size_type size() const
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    // conversion operators
    operator std::vector<char>() const;
    operator bool() const;

    template <class In> void insert(iterator dest, In b, In e)
    {
        data.insert(dest, b, e);
    }

};

Str operator+(const Str& s1, const Str& s2)
{
    Str s = s1;
    s += s2;
    return s;
}

Str::operator std::vector<char>() const
{
    std::vector<char> ret = data;
    return ret;

}

Str::operator bool() const
{
    if (data.size() > 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}


int main()

{

    Str name = "Joe";
    Str greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A few bits that would be useful to know: what type is `name` declared as? I'm confused why `operator+(const char [8], int)` is being considered; could you include the declarations for your `Std::operator+` and its constructor(s) here please, as well as any other relevant conversion operators for `Str`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Don't you need to overload the conversion operator from String to Str as well? Since   `"Hello, " + name + "!";` will most likely generate a string

Comment: `'built-in C++ operator+(const char [8], int)'` suggests it is converting name to an int type. const char[8] is your `Hello, \0"

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. I have edited my question above to add a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. "name" is a Str type object.